# Prompt for Credentials Repeatedly in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the below code which prompts for username and password, and if incorrect has the right exceptions that are caught in the catch statement. However, how do I ensure I repeatedly prompt for username and password until a correct one is entered?

Another question is how do I convert the password entered into a secure string. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$TS_Deploy_Group = "MYADGROUP"

$get_AD_Server = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetWorkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.DNSDomain -like "***-**.contoso.com"}).DnsDomain      

if ($get_AD_Server -ne $null)
{
    $get_Nearest_DC = (Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $get_AD_Server -Discover -NextClosestSite).Name

    $AD_Server = $get_Nearest_DC,$get_AD_Server -join "." 

    $cred = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Authenticate to OSD:", "Enter your Operator Credentials", "", "") 

}
else
{
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please make sure you are connected to the Corporate Network")
} 

    
Try
{   
    $ADauth = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $TS_Deploy_Group -Recursive -Server $AD_Server -Credential $cred
}
Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] 
{       
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The user" +$cred.username+ "has not been found", "User not found")
}

Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADServerDownException] 
{       
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Check the server name or IP configuration", "Error while contacting AD Server")    
}

Catch [System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException]      
{       
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please check the admin user name or password", "Invalid credentials")                                      
}       

if (($ADauth.name -Contains $cred.username) -ne $true) {

[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The specified user is not member of the group: 

$TS_Deploy_Group", "Unauthorized user")

exit

}

Finally 
{

[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Task Sequence Will Continue to the Next Step")                                     

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
while($true)
{

Try
{   
    $ADauth = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $TS_Deploy_Group -Recursive -Server $AD_Server -Credential $cred
    break
}
Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] 
{       
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The user" +$cred.username+ "has not been found", "User not found")
    $cred = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Authenticate to OSD:", "Enter your Operator Credentials", "", "") 
}

Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADServerDownException] 
{       
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Check the server name or IP configuration", "Error while contacting AD Server") 
}

Catch [System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException]      
{       
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please check the admin user name or password", "Invalid credentials")   
    $cred = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Authenticate to OSD:", "Enter your Operator Credentials", "", "")                                    
}   
}
```